# Running code with another interpreter on a Perl script

Tags: python, perl

[This thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74244/hybrid-code-in-shell-scripts-sharing-variables) discusses a way of running Python code from within a Bash script.

Is there any way to do something similar from within a Perl script? i.e. is there any way to **run Python code typed on a Perl script?** Note that I am not asking about running a Python **file** from a Perl script. I am asking about running Python code directly typed within the same file that has the Perl script (in the same way that the other thread discussed how to run Perl code from which a Bash script).

Example:

```
# /bin/perl
use 5.010
my $some_perl_variable = 'hello';


# ... BEGIN PYTHON BLOCK ...
# We are still in the same file. But we are now running Python code
import sys;
print some_perl_variable # Notice that this is a perl variable
for r in range(3):
  print r
# ... END PYTHON BLOCK ...

say "We are done with the Perl script!" 
say "The output of the Python block is:"
print $output" 
1;
```

Should print:

```
We are done with the Perl script! 
The output of the Python block is: 
hello
1
2 
3
```

We are done with the perl script

Comment: Yes, the same technique (heredocs) applies. See also the `-e` and `-E` options for so-called “one-liners”.

Comment: It would help if you described what you wanted to do. Do you want to run Python code from within a Perl script? That is my best guess from what you have written.

Comment: @Borodin I updated the OP significantly. Let me know if that is still not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you would be interested in the [`Inline`](https://metacpan.org/module/Inline) module. It allows Perl to call code in many other languages, and relies on support modules for each language.

You don't say what you want to do, but you mention Python and there is an [`Inline::Python`](https://metacpan.org/module/Inline%3a%3aPython).

Comment: Ah, but Inline::Python can run python code that "lives on a file", which the OP is afraid of. Sure, it can also (and more commonly does) run python code that lives in a string and/or inlined directly in the perl script (hence the name)—but even in those cases, the perl script usually lives in a file, so unless the python is generated dynamically… and even then, memory is basically a file (literally so, on linux). I think the only solution is to make sure the python code never lives at all. :)

Comment: Or, more seriously… yeah, it seems like a 50/50 chance you guessed right, and it may be a useful answer even if you didn't, so definitely +1.

Comment: @abarnert I updated the OP. I hope the problem is a lot clearer now. Sorry my question was confusing at the beginning.

Comment: @user815423426: If you want to share variables between Python and Perl, the usual way to do that is to call a Python function with your Perl variable or vice-versa. The docs explain this pretty well, and give lots of examples. If you need to access global variables, it's trickier (for different reasons in each direction), but the docs show that as well, so read them first, then ask any specific questions.

Comment: @abarnert: Someone has given you +1 but I have no idea what you mean by *"call a Python function with your Perl variable"*. Please explain, for I am but mortal

Comment: @user815423426: From your updated question, it looks like you need `Inline::Python` as I linked in my answer. I am still unsure about what you mean by *"typed on a Perl script"* but am still voting for that module

Comment: @abarnert: I don't think the OP is *afraid* of being able to run code that *"lives on a file"*. I think they simply don't need that, and rather want to be able to add Python code inside their Perl script.

Comment: @Borodin: By "call a Python function with your Perl variable" I mean do exactly what the `Inline::Python` docs describe with almost the exact same wording. I don't know how to explain it any clearer than that. If you think the OP will not understand the docs, and that someone should summarize them here, and that someone should not be you, I'll add an answer. But I think your answer is probably sufficient as-is; `Inline` is not that hard to figure out.

Comment: @abarnet: OK if you mean *what `Inline::Python` does* then that's fine. But my issue is with your *"the usual way to do that"*, because there is no *usual way* to run Python from within Perl. Apart from that, your "solution" seems to be a restatement of the OP's problem. He may as well have said *"How do I call a Python function with [my] Perl variable?"*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the same technique (here-docs) can be used for Perl.

Perl in Bash:

```
perl <<'END' # note single quotes to avoid $variable interpolation
use 5.010;
say "hello world";
END
```

or

```
perl -E'say "hello from perl"'
```

Bash in Perl:

```
use autodie; # less error handling
open my $bash, "|-", "bash";
print $bash <<'END'; # single quotes again
echo hello from bash
END
```

Perl in Bash in Perl:

```
use autodie; # less error handling
open my $bash, "|-", "bash";
print $bash <<'END'; # single quotes again
perl <<'INNER_END'
 use 5.010;
 say "hello inception";
INNER_END
END
```

(which I ironically tested on the commandline, in another heredoc)

Comment: You may be right: he just wants to put Perl code into a Bash script. In that case the question should be tagged differently :-/  We won't know until he stops his silence on the matter

Comment: Great. Thanks amon and @Borodin. What about sharing variables between Python and Perl (see my updated OP)

Comment: @user815423426: That second followup belongs on Borodin's answer, not this one.

Comment: @abarnert: You are guilty of making a slightly ambiguous question far more ambiguous. Please, we don't need *more* ways of understanding the question, we need to wait until the OP explains themselves.

Comment: @Borodin: The OP specifically said "What about sharing variables between Python and Perl", so I think it's no longer ambiguous that he wants to run Python code from Perl, not just Bash code.